# move/translate values of 2d array by a specific amount (up)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I would like to understand various 2d array translation approaches.

I have a method which returns a list of (x, y) coordinate indexes corresponding to values that should be deleted in the 2d array. Values below should take the place of the value to be deleted, and values below that, should be moved into their's place, etc. At the bottom of the array, new values will be randomly generated (help not required here, and out of scope), denoted by r in the example outputs below.

simple example input:

```
coordinates = [
    (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)
]
test = numpy.array([
    [0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 1, 3],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4, 1],
    [2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 4, 3],
    [3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2],
    [2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 2],
    [3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1],
])
```

simple example output:

```
numpy.array([
    [0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 1, 3],
    [2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 4, 1],
    [3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 3],
    [2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2],
    [0, 0, 1, 4, 3, 4, 4],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0],
    [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2],
    [r, r, r, 1, 3, 2, 1],
])
```

complex example input:

```
coordinates = [
    (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3),
    (3, 4), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (5, 2), (6, 2),
]
test = numpy.array([
    [0, 3, 0, 4, 1, 1, 3],
    [4, 1, 0, 4, 2, 4, 1],
    [2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3],
    [3, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 2],
    [2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 2],
    [3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1],
])
```

complex example output:

```
numpy.array([
    [0, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3],
    [4, 1, 0, 2, 2, 4, 1],
    [2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2],
    [3, 1, 3, r, 3, 4, 4],
    [2, 0, 1, r, 3, 2, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, r, r, 4, 2],
    [0, 2, 1, r, r, 2, 1],
    [3, r, r, r, r, r, r],
])
```

A variety of solutions welcomed, simplicity and efficiency preferred, exemplified answers appreciated!

Injecting `coordinates` and `test` variables from examples above;

```
import numpy

NUM_ROWS = len(test)
NUM_COLS = len(test[0])

for row_i in range(NUM_ROWS - 1, 0 - 1, -1):  # reverse loop rows (B -> T)
    for col_i in range(NUM_COLS):
        if (col_i, row_i) in coordinates:
            for lower_row_i in range(row_i + 1, NUM_ROWS):
                test[lower_row_i - 1][col_i] = test[lower_row_i][col_i]
            test[NUM_ROWS - 1][col_i] = numpy.random.randint(5)

print(test)
```

creates the desired outputs, but there must be a number of other ways of doing this which are more clean, efficient, simple, etc.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: the coordinates that you used are inverted. Numpy indexing would be (row, col) where you use (col, row). The solution below uses transposition to adapt to your coordinates.*

I would craft a boolean mask to identify the positions to delete/shift. Then use `argsort` to push the `True` values to the end and use these indices to reorder the original array.

```
m = np.zeros_like(test, dtype=bool).T
m[tuple(zip(*coordinates))] = True

out = np.take_along_axis(test, np.argsort(m).T, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3],
       [4, 1, 0, 2, 2, 4, 1],
       [2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2],
       [3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4],
       [2, 0, 1, 4, 3, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 4, 3, 4, 2],
       [0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1],
       [3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3]])
```

##### intermediates

Boolean `m` (as integer for nicer display):

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Result of `np.argsort(m).T`:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 3, 3, 7, 5, 3, 3],
       [3, 4, 4, 0, 6, 4, 4],
       [4, 5, 5, 1, 7, 5, 5],
       [5, 6, 6, 2, 2, 6, 6],
       [6, 7, 7, 3, 3, 7, 7],
       [7, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2]])
```

##### masking

If you want to mask the shifted values

```
out[np.take_along_axis(m.T, np.argsort(m).T, axis=0)] = -1
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0,  3,  0,  1,  1,  1,  3],
       [ 4,  1,  0,  2,  2,  4,  1],
       [ 2,  1,  1,  1,  0,  2,  2],
       [ 3,  1,  3, -1,  3,  4,  4],
       [ 2,  0,  1, -1,  3,  2,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  0, -1, -1,  4,  2],
       [ 0,  2,  1, -1, -1,  2,  1],
       [ 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]])
```